# fastest way to remove whitespace from a rendered PHP file

Tags: php

I tried a performance check tool "DOM Monster" to analyze my php site. There is one information which says "50% of nodes are whitespace-only text nodes".
Ok I unterstand the problem but what is the fastest way to cleanup whitespace in php?

I think a good start is to use the "Output Control" like ob_start() and then replace the whitespace before releasing it with ob_end_flush(). In the moment I do everything with echo echo ... I never read much about this ob_* things is it useful?

I guess using preg_replace() is a performance killer for this job or?
So what is the best practice for this?

Comment: Why not address the problem at its source, i.e. where the nodes are generated?

Comment: Let your webserver handle compression (which includes more than simple whitespace) http://uk.php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php as most modern browsers support Accept-Encoding: gzip

Comment: That zlib compression (which should definitely be used!) only helps with bandwidth. It won’t help with parsing the page source.

Comment: such a compression isn't useful at all

Comment: Parsing time is increased by the nodes depth, not by the actual whitespaces.

Comment: ob_start() is the correct approach. preg_replace() is no performance killer, but the most optimal solution for that. However it's not very worthwhile. Browser engines are optimized for real world HTML, which contains heaps of spaces. Also such approaches can eat up significant whitespace `here</a><b>or</b>there</p>`.

Comment: @Kissaki - true, compression won't help parsing/rendering in the browser, but should definitely be used to reduce bandwith @Col Shrapnel - Not everybody in the world has 100MB connections, so compression has some value for those with internet connections running at lesser speeds... but the real solution is almost certainly to clean up the markup of the page

Comment: Seriously!? Are you sure you understand the problem? So you have a few empty DOM nodes. You might be using them for data in the page with scripting or for display using their size or color. If not, then why does your HTML have empty text nodes at all....

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way to remove whitespace-only nodes is to not create them in the first place. Just remove all the whitespace immediately before and after each HTML tag.

You certainly *could* remove the spaces from your code after the fact using an output handler (look at the `callback` bit in [ob_start](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)), but if your goal is performance, then that kind of defeats the purpose.

A whitespace-only node is in the DOM tree parsed by the browser when it reads your HTML. It's where there's an HTML tag, then nothing but whitespace, then another HTML tag. It's a waste of browser resources, but not a huge deal.

Answer (score 0):

The function trim() will solve your problem, isn't it?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: trim only trims right and left its the same as running a rtrim then a ltrim

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you talk about HTML, and HTML is as is a meta language full of whitespace (attributes, texts).
By the way, you probably use newlines for readability.

I rather advise you to compress your page with deflate/gzip and webserver rules, ie an .htaccess rule:

```
<FilesMatch "\\.(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
```

You can also take a look at [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) which is a library to help you to check and cleanup your HTML code.

Comment: deflate/gzip will not trim whitespace, and that’s what the question was about

Comment: I don't think that the good answer is necessarly the answer the OP was looking for, when this one looks like a bad idea. IMHO I rather advise about a better way to optimize perfomance instead of losing time in remover crappy whitespaces. Finnaly, it is for the sake a of the end-user.

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace will of course slow things down a little. But probably it's the fastest way anyway. The problem is more that preg_replace may be unreliable because it is very hard to write regular expression that works on all possible cases.
If you are createing XML/XHTML output, you could parse all your data using a fast stream parser SAX or StAX, php has both builtin usually, and then write the data back to the output without the whitespaces. That's simple, effective, reliable und at least medium fast. It's still not going to blow you off with speed.

Another option would be to just use gzip. (ob_handler('gz_handler') is the call in php if I remember correctly). This will compress your data and compression works extremely well on problems with data that repeats a lot within a document. That come with a litte performance penalty as well, but the reduced size of the output document may make up for it.
Though beware that the output will not be send to the browser before all output is available. This makes partial loading of webpages much harder ;-).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using ob_* and then trimming whitespace is that you’ll have to make sure to not remove displayed whitespace like in `<pre>` tags or `<textarea>`s etc. You’ll need a syntactical parser which understands where it should not trim.

With an (performance-)expensive parser you should also cache output where possible.

Comment: You do not post a answer explaining why another answer is wrong thats what a comment is for.

Comment: What do you mean “why another answer is wrong”? I didn’t imply or say other answers were wrong.

Comment: The /answer/ in that answer was that you’ll need a parser which understands HTML. Just removing (all) whitespace is not enough. (The parser can be a simple one only checking a subset of HTML ofc, with regexp or programmatically.)

Answer (score -3):

The following is code to remove all space characters but the first of a sequence of spaces. So 1 space will be kept, 3 spaces pruned to 1, etc.

at the top of you php file do

```
ob_start();
```

At the end do

```
function StripExtraSpace($s)
{
  $newstr = "";
  for($i = 0; $i < strlen($s); $i++)
  {
    $newstr = $newstr . substr($s, $i, 1);
    if(substr($s, $i, 1) == ' ')
      while(substr($s, $i + 1, 1) == ' ')
        $i++;
  }

  return $newstr;
}

$content = ob_get_clean();
echo StripExtraSpace($content);
```

Comment: Exactly what is asked for, it removes all white space from the end result, it allows single space's but removed extra same as the browser  parsing needs

Comment: I meant explain the code a bit to get an idea what it does without analysing it.

Comment: I formatted the code and added a short descr. to the answer now. After formatting I was able to read it better and understand it. :)

Comment: It appears that StripExtraSpace could be abbreviated to the more efficient `$s=preg_replace("/ +/"," ",$s)`. However, for what it's worth, the solution won't actually remove any whitepace-only text nodes.